# Greater control of search results using $snippet

Tags: 7, search

In *node--content_type.tpl.php* I can do the following:

```
hide($content['body']);
print render($content);
```

Can I draw and hide field elements from a node's content in a similar way from `$snippet;` on *search-result.tpl.php*?

If not how do I gain greater control of the placement of images and body text in search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the best way to have control over the display of each result was to comment out all of the default information that is rendered in *search-result.tpl.php* and instead load and render each result in its teaser form. I achieved this in the following way:

```
$view = node_view($result['node'], 'teaser');
print render($view);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I draw and hide field elements from a node's content in a similar way from $snippet; on search-result.tpl.php?

You cannot, as `$snippet` is a string, not an render array. In fact, the default template used by Drupal contains the following code.

```
<?php if ($snippet): ?>
  <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What you can do is implementing `hook_preprocess_search_result()` to change the content of `$variables['snippet']` with the content you want to show. See [template_preprocess_search_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) for a list of the variables passed to the preprocess function.

As you seem interested to alter what shown as result for a node search, you could also implement `theme_search_result__node()` as `template_preprocess_search_result()` use the following code to set the theme hook suggestions array.

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_result__' . $variables['module'];
```

The documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) says:

> There are two special variables that these preprocess and process functions can set: 'theme_hook_suggestion' and 'theme_hook_suggestions'. These will be merged together to form a list of 'suggested' alternate theme hooks to use, in reverse order of priority. theme_hook_suggestion will always be a higher priority than items in theme_hook_suggestions. `theme()` will use the highest priority implementation that exists. If none exists, `theme()` will use the implementation for the theme hook it was called with. These suggestions are similar to and are used for similar reasons as calling `theme()` with an array as the $hook parameter (see below). The difference is whether the suggestions are determined by the code that calls theme() or by a preprocess or process function.